# Pass props to underlying screens

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have the following nested structur:

```
- StackNavigator
 - TabBar
   - TabScreen1
   - TabScreen2
   - TabScreen3
   - TabScreen4
 - NormalScreen
```

The main stacknavigator is called like this:

```
<Router notifications={6} />
```

And looks like this:

```
    const Router = StackNavigator({
  MainTabBar: { screen: MainTabBar },
  ChartDetailScreen: { screen: ChartDetailScreen },
}, {
  headerMode: 'none',
  initialRouteName: 'MainTabBar',
});
```

In one of these TabScreens I need to access the `notifications` property, which is passed to the stacknavigator.

The screens configuration basically looks like this :

```
Screen1: {
      screen: Screen1,
      navigationOptions: {
        tabBarLabel: 'Screen1',
        tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
          <Image ... />), <-- I need notifications here!
      },
    },
```

How do I pass the `notification` prop of the outer stacknavigator to this/all screens? I tried to access `screenProps` with `navigationOptions: (screenProps) => {...}`, but there didn't appear this property.

I use React Navigation `"version": "1.0.0-beta.19"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should construct your `navigationOptions` as a function:

```
navigationOptions: ({ screenProps }) => ({
  tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
    <Image notifications={screenProps.notifications} />
  ),
  ...
});
```

And then pass `screenProps` (https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/stack#Navigator-Props) as an object, like:

```
<Router screenProps={{ notifications: 6 }} />
```

This should do the thing.

Comment: Oh, true. It was `=` on my code. Now fixed - thanks. Can you accept this answer, btw?